# Disable submit button if all character counters aren't OK

Tags: jquery

We have a very simple word counter that is working fine enough for our needs. We now need to make a modification to it though. Please see our JSfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/MUSXU/1

```
(function($){
    $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
        // setting the defaults
        // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
        var defaults = {
            limit: 100
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // and the plugin begins
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj, text, wordcount, limited;

            obj = $(this);
            obj.after('<span style="font-size: 11px; clear: both; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" id="counter-text">Max. '+options.limit+' words</span>');

            obj.keyup(function() {
                text = obj.val().replace(/\s+/g, " ");;
                if(text === "") {
                    wordcount = 0;
                } else {
                    wordcount = $.trim(text).split(" ").length;
                    var URLs = text.match(/([^\s])+\.(com|net|org|biz|gov|edu|mobi|info|ca|us|mil)/g);
                    if(URLs != null && URLs.length > 0){
                      wordcount += (URLs.length*2);
                    }
                }
                if(wordcount > options.limit) {
                   obj.next().html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">-' + parseInt(wordcount - options.limit, 10) + ' words left</span>');

                    $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    obj.next().html((options.limit - wordcount)+' words left');
                $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                } 
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('textarea').textareaCounter({limit:15});
```

We have one issue though:

1. We need the submit button to remain disabled if ANY of the character counters on the page are over their limits. Right now, the way we have it coded, the submit button is successfully disabled when the word count goes over, but it's immediately re-enabled as soon as you type into the next textarea.

I am not that great at javascript and have just sort of hacked this together for our needs, and this is the final thing that I need working before we can deploy it.

I'd appreciate any help you can lend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array to hold your results to check for validation.  see this...

http://jsfiddle.net/kmd97/Up9KS/

```
var res = [];

 $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                    $.each(res, function (index, value) {
                        if (value) {
                            $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
                            return false;
                        }
```

add this bit onload to mimic a keypress, probably the cleanest/simplest way to achieve the validation upfront.

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keyup");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 40;
$("textarea").trigger(press);
```

Comment: That is great, thank you! I knew that was what we needed to do, but I wasn't sure how to accomplish it.

I did just realize another small issue though when I clicked your link - If the textareas already have content in them, the counter doesn't reflect that on the pageload. How can we correct that?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, take a look at the bit added to the end.  And I updated the fiddle link.

Comment: I hate to be a bother, but now I'm experiencing more fun issues. When I try to address each textarea individually using your code, the counters get all screwed up (http://jsfiddle.net/Up9KS/3/). But using my original code, they worked fine (http://jsfiddle.net/MUSXU/11/). Any ideas?

Comment: Check my fiddle link again and see if that is working any better for you...sorry i was too quick with the first answer I skipped over some important parts

Comment: So that's working great on Jsfiddle, but not so great on the site. Everything is working fine on the site, save for one thing: The submit button is never being disabled. I have double and triple checked the ID and it looks fine, so I'm at a loss as to why it's not working. I think something weird is happening with the res array in that I'm not sure if it ever stores a true value. The counter keeps going into the negative, but when I do a console.log of the array, it always has false for the textarea in question.  You wouldn't want to perhaps diagnose on the live site would you?

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a look.  You can post it here or send to the email in my profile if you don't want it exposed yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24474/discussion-between-kevin-and-kmd97)